# How to delete source zip files while using ditto command on Mac?

Tags: macos, unix, zip

I have several Zip folders (produced by Google Takeout service) and I want to merge them since Google provides many small Zips as an output. For the sake of merging I've chosen to use **ditto** command on Mac, which will merge all files/folders including the metadata.

Now, the problem I have is this: **ditto** command creates another copy of the source zip file and places it into destination folder. I would like this source zip file to be deleted after extraction and have *no copy of the zip added to the destination folder* due to the limited size of the HDD. Each of 35 Zip files weights about 50Gb. Any ideas how I should alter my command?

So far my intended line of command would be:

```
ditto -x -k -V *.zip result 1>log.txt 2>&1
```